# How to conditionally import dependencies in a module shared between React (Next.js) and React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, next.js

I want to build a shared Typescript module for the React (Next.js) web app and the React Native mobile apps.

This module would handle all the calls to the backend (Firebase) as well as state management with the context API.

The issue is that React and React Native don't use the same packages for the same tasks.

Basically I need to do:

```
import react from 'react',
if (platform == 'mobile') {
  import app from '@react-native-firebase/app'
  import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'
  import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
  import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage'
} else if (platform == 'web') {
  import app from 'firebase/app'
  import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
  import auth from 'firebase/auth'
  import storage from 'firebase/storage'  
} else // throw some error
```

Of course, this code will not work. Is there a solution for that ?

Thanks

Comment: You could have a step in your build that takes an environment variable and parses & edits the files with the correct imports before the actual build

Answer (score 1):

To differentiate between the requests of either web app/ react-native mobile app, you can look at the options which mobile app doesn't support. For instance, localStorage, is a window method on the browser, and it is not available to mobile devices. To decide the platform you can check for,

```
            if(typeof(localStorage)) {
               //Browser module initialization
              }
            else {
              //Mobile module initialization like AsyncStorage
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if windows existe on the plateforme

```
if(windows ==underfined ) {
// mobile plateforme
}else{
// web plateforme
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Do two separate builds to produce 2 artifacts 1 for each platform and use webpack resolve alias to change where the default import comes from.

Imports can't be conditionally resolved in ESM as their always hoisted; you can use dynamic imports however these return Promises which can make them harder to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use 2 files:

```
directory
| - imports.ts
| - imports.native.ts
```

When I write for example:

```
import { package1, package2 } from '../directory/imports.ts'
```

React Native knows it need to import from imports.native.ts rather than imports.ts. It is a build-in functionality.